# "read $#" fails ("not a valid identifier"). What does this mean?

Tags: bash, arguments

Can anyone help me with this code? bash doesn't recognize the $2 only the first $1 show an error: `read: '2': it is not a valid identificator`.

```
#!/bin/bash
read $#
a=$#
```

Comment: What do you expect `read $#` to do?

Comment: There's a lot else that's wrong with this too -- it's larger than a single question can/should answer. Run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix what it finds.

Comment: I've pruned code unrelated to the narrow technical question -- previously this was too broad to be within site rules. See docs on building a [mcve] -- a good code sample is focused on showcasing a single, specific error, with everything unrelated or unnecessary to produce that error removed.

Comment: I expect $# read all arguments I write at moment of running it. About $qq or $qw I change it by $1 and $2 respectively

Comment: You don't need to use `read` for `$1`, `$2`, `$#`, etc. to be available. They're  defined the moment your script starts. `read` is only used to read from stdin (and assign to another variable). Any variable whose contents are intended to come from somewhere other than stdin shouldn't be subject to `read`.

Comment: `$#` is the number of command-line arguments.  The syntax for `read` is `read ... name`, where "name" is the name of a variable.  Variable names can only start with an alpha or an underscore, so `#` cannot be altered directly, and neither can 1 or 2.  Note that a variable name DOES NOT start with a `$`, the leading `$` is a unary operator which gives the *value* of the variable.  So to read into variable `fred` from stdin we `read fred`, to display its value we `echo $fred`.  Do a `help read` on the command-line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot read into `$#`, *or* into the variable called `2` (which `$#` expands to).

Instead, to reassign `$2`, you need to use `set` to completely rewrite the full set of positional parameters:

```
set -- one two
```

...will set `$2` to `two`, and `$#` to `2` (since two items were provided).

---

By contrast, if you simply wish to use the value for `$2` passed on your script's command line, you don't need to (and shouldn't) use `read` at all.

By contrast, if you want to access the *last* command-line argument, you can use indirect expansion for that:

```
set -- one two last
last_arg=$#          # sets last_arg=3
result=${!last_arg}  # sets result=last
```

...or, if you want to overwrite the last command-line argument with a value read from stdin:

```
read new_last
set -- "${@:1:$(( $# - 1 ))}" "$new_last"
```

Comment: I was running it on terminal and it works it works:  ./"namescript.sh py($1) sh($2)

Comment: Yes -- if you're passing in your arguments, you have no need for `set --` to override them. However, in no circumstance does `read $#` do something useful.

Comment: Thanks for helping but  I have another question: how can I do it to compare values between arguments?

Comment: You mean like `if [ "$1" = "$2" ]; then echo "Both arguments are the same"; fi`? (Generally, a second question should be asked as a separate question, but I'm happy to at least help narrow down what that question would be).

Comment: It´s more like if [ "$du -hc $1" -lt "$du -hc $2" ]; then echo "$1 is less than $2";fi

Comment: Then you need `[ "$(du -c "$1")" -lt "$(du -c "$2")" ]`, but making sure the options you pass to `du` are such that its output is numeric. (If `-h` specifies human-readable output, then, that might not work so well). Running your script with `bash -x` will show exactly which options are being passed to `[`, so you can see what `du` is actually emitting and how it compares to what you want/expect.

Comment: Thanks. Another way I found is using stat -c%s but I prefer to use du